# Seleniumでマウスを動かすと、ビューポート域内にもかかわらずエラーが発生する

Tags: python, selenium

## 解決したい現象

Seleniumでマウスを人間が動かすように見える疑似的な関数を作成しようとした時、マウスがビューポート域内にもかかわらずエラーが出てしまいます。
この現象は仕様なのでしょうか、私の使い方や考え方の間違いなのでしょうか。
ご指摘いただけますようお願いいたします。

解決したい現象は「ビューポート内をエラー無くマウス移動させたい」です。

**対象のコード:**

```
move_to_element_with_offset(br.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html'), x,y)
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds
```

---

以下のような実験コードを書いてみました。

## 実験コード

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import math

def get_chrome(width=640, height=480):
    """Selenium Chrome Browserを取得する"""
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.set_window_size(width, height)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    return driver

def get_firefox(width=640, height=480):
    """Selenium Firefox Browserを取得する"""
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_window_size(width, height)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    return driver

def get_viewport_size(br):
    """ JavaScriptを使用してビューポートのサイズを取得 """
    width  = br.execute_script("return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)")
    height = br.execute_script("return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)")
    return width, height

def get_mouse_move_area(br):
    """ マウスの可動域を調べる"""
    size = br.get_window_size()
    view_size = get_viewport_size(br)
    base_element = br.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
    base_point = base_element.location

    print(f"基準タグ<html>の位置 {base_point['x']} , {base_point['y']}")
    print(f"ブラウザのサイズ     {size['width']} x {size['height']}")
    print(f"ビューポートのサイズ {view_size[0]} x {view_size[1]}")

    start_x = math.floor(view_size[0]*0.45) # 検査時間を短くするための0.45
    start_y = math.floor(view_size[1]*0.45)

    print(f"マウス検査範囲 {start_x}-{view_size[0]} , {start_y}-{view_size[1]}")

    for x in range(start_x, view_size[0]):
        try:
            ActionChains(br).move_to_element_with_offset(base_element, x,0).perform()
        except:
            print(f"マウスX座標エラー {x}")
            break

    for y in range(start_y, view_size[1]):
        try:
            ActionChains(br).move_to_element_with_offset(base_element, 0,y).perform()
        except:
            print(f"マウスY座標エラー {y}")
            break
    print(f"マウスの可動域 0-{x-1} , 0-{y-1}")
    return (x-1,y-1)
        

print("ChromeDriver でマウスの可動域を調べる")
driver = get_chrome(640, 480)
get_mouse_move_area(driver)

print("ChromeDriver でGoogleを開いてマウスの可動域を調べる")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
get_mouse_move_area(driver)


print("FireFoxDriver でマウスの可動域を調べる")
driver = get_firefox(640, 480)
get_mouse_move_area(driver)

print("FireFoxDriver でGoogleを開いてマウスの可動域を調べる")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
get_mouse_move_area(driver)
```

#### 結果

```
ChromeDriver でマウスの可動域を調べる
基準タグ<html>の位置    0 , 0
ブラウザのサイズ     640 x 480
ビューポートのサイズ 624 x 342
マウス検査範囲 280-624 , 153-342
マウスX座標エラー 313
マウスY座標エラー 339
マウスの可動域 0-312 , 0-338

ChromeDriver でGoogleを開いてマウスの可動域を調べる
基準タグ<html>の位置 0 , 0
ブラウザのサイズ     640 x 480
ビューポートのサイズ 624 x 342
マウス検査範囲 280-624 , 153-342
マウスX座標エラー 322
マウスY座標エラー 172
マウスの可動域 0-321 , 0-171

FireFoxDriver でマウスの可動域を調べる
基準タグ<html>の位置 0 , 0
ブラウザのサイズ     640 x 480
ビューポートのサイズ 628 x 389
マウス検査範囲 282-628 , 175-389
マウスX座標エラー 315
マウスY座標エラー 386
マウスの可動域 0-314 , 0-385

FireFoxDriver でGoogleを開いてマウスの可動域を調べる
基準タグ<html>の位置 0 , 0
ブラウザのサイズ     640 x 480
ビューポートのサイズ 628 x 389
マウス検査範囲 282-628 , 175-389
マウスX座標エラー 315
マウスY座標エラー 196
マウスの可動域 0-314 , 0-195
```

※基準位置が(0,0)になるように基準elementを'body'から'html'に変更しました。

## 環境

Windows 11 22H2
Python 3.9.13
selenium 4.16.0
ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.130（Official Build） （64 ビット）
FirefoxDriver 121.0 (64-bit)

#### スキル

Python 初心者

Comment: ChromeDriverをご使用ですか？そうならバージョンはどれですか？

Comment: ドライバーのバージョンを忘れておりました。ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.130（Official Build） （64 ビット）です。

Comment: move_to_element_with_offsetの指定された要素の位置はどうなっているでしょうか？

Comment: move_to_element_with_offset の x,y にそれぞれ 0からインクリメントしています。
そしてエラーが起きた場所が
X:313
Y:335
だったので
マウスの可動域は X:0-312 ,Y:0-334 と判断しました。

Comment: 分かりにくかったでしょうか？「move_to_element_with_offsetの指定された要素の位置」とはmove_to_element_with_offsetの引数に指定した要素の位置(offsetする基準位置)のことです。

Comment: 勘違いで申し訳ございませんでした。   
タグ<body>を基準にしています。   
element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')   
point = element.location   
print(f"bodyの位置 {point['x']} x {point['y']}")   
bodyの位置 8 x 8 と表示されました。

Comment: 私の環境(Windows11, Chrome, JupyterLab)で試したところではエラーなく実行できて「(625, 342)」が表示されました。

Comment: 貴重な情報ありがとうございます。
環境依存の可能性があることがわかり対策が考えやすくなりました。